# Error in Qt program

Tags: c++, qt

This code

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("my first app");
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Causing an error:

> QLabel: there is no such directory

I am using Qt 5.0.1 in Windows

Comment: `QLabel *label=new QLebel("my first app");` Is that how the line is in your code or is it a type? `QLebel`

Comment: Also, as you use `QtWidgets/QApplication`, shouldn't it be `QtGui/QLabel`?

Comment: Can you copy-and-paste the *exact* error message?

Comment: I have done all you said but still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

change

```
#include <QLabel>
```

to `#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>`
This is where `QLabel` actually resides (if this is that `QLabel` that you want)

Answer (score 0):

Put QT += widgets in your .pro file.